# Accessibility list read iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Is there any way for a tableview to read as a list for accessibility while having the whole focus on the tableview?
For example: I have a list like

1. Art
2. Ball
3. Car
4. Dog

So I would want the accessibility reader to read as "Item 1 of 4 Art, Item 2 of 4 Ball, .... etc"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but you would have to implement that manually.

You can create some kind of model for your cell which you use to configure it.
You would need to pass the total row count of your table view to that configuration for each cell.

```
struct CellConfig {
  let title: String
  private let count: Int

  init(title: String, count: Int) {
    self.title = title
    self.count = count
  }
}
```

You could than actually extend the functionality to let the `CellConfig` return the correct accessibility label by passing the current `IndexPath` like so:

```
struct CellConfig {
  ...

  func axLabel(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> String {
    let currentElement = indexPath.row + 1
    return "Item \(currentElement) of \(count). \(title)."
  }
}
```

So when returning your cell from your delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard indexPath.row < items.count else { return UITableViewCell() }
        let item = items[indexPath.row] // The array here holds all the configs of every cell.
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as? UITabelViewCell

        cell?.titleLabel.text = item.title
        cell?.accessibilityLabel = item.axLabel(for: indexPath)

        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }
```